# Kernel restarts when calling self defined function which adds together lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda, crash, kernel, restart

I've tried to define a function that adds several lambda functions together.
When I call the function the kernel crashes and restarts with no further error messages.

```
def add_lambdas(function_list):
    f = lambda x, y: None
    for function in function_list:
        f = lambda x, y: f(x, y) + function(x, y)
    return f

f1 = lambda x, y: x + y
f2 = lambda x, y: x**2 - 2*y

f3 = lambda x, y: f1(x,y) + f2(x,y)
f4 = add_lambdas([f1,f2])
```

For example, when I call f3(2,3) all is well, but when I call f4(2,3) the kernel crashes and restarts. For f3 I do the adding of f1 and f2 manually, but for f4 I pass them through the function add_lambdas().

This is the output:

```
In[5]: f3(2,3)
Out[5]: 3

In[6]: f4(2,3)

Restarting kernel...
```

Obviously something is wrong with my defined function, but I cant figure out what it is. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're defining `f` as a recursive function, which I don't think is what you want. You can try this instead:

```py
def add_lambdas(function_list):
    return lambda x, y: sum(f(x, y) for f in function_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a stack overflow.  The problem is that there is only a single variable `f` and a single variable `function` in `add_lambdas`.  When you write:

`f = lambda x, y: f(x, y) + function(x, y)`

you are just assigning a new value to the variable `f`, but the variable `f` inside the definition is also that new value.  This is the stack overflow.  In addition, the variable `function` will be left with the last value in the list.  There is no reason for it to copy the value.

If instead you write:
`f = lambda x, y, f=f, function=function: f(x, y) + function(x, y)`,
you're telling Python to assign `f` and `function` to new variables, (with the same name) and to use those new variables inside the lambda.  Changes made to the other variables are immaterial

You'll discover a different error in your code.  The first line needs to be
`f = lambda x, y: 0` since otherwise you're adding an integer to `None`.

---

Note that @josemz is the simpler solution if you're just planning on adding things. If you want to learn to use lambdas within other lambdas, you need to make sure variables are bound correctly.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! This helped alot.

Comment: Where this really bites you is when you write something like `[lambda x: x + i for i in range(10)]`.  You think you have an array of 10 functions, the first of which adds 0, the second adds 1, and so forth.  But there is only one `i`, and when we're done `i=9`, so you've got an array of ten functions, all of which add 9.  You need to write `[lambda x, i=i: x + 1 for i in range(10)]` so that `i` gets copied to a new variable.